# How do I create separate dataframes or CSVs from a nested JSON with unrelated branches?

Tags: python, json, dataframe, csv, nested

I have nested JSON files with multiple separate branches that can only be joined through the information at the top of the branches. I do not want to cross-join the rows from the different branches. The braches can have inside them lists and dictionaries which can further have other lists and dictionaries.

Following is a sample json file. I have 35 different files with different structures. I want to create separate flat files for each branch that will be stored in separate folders. Later on, data from these files will be processed and queried.

```
"Shipment": {
    "ActualShipmentDate": "2020-03-22",
    "EnterpriseCode": "US001",
    "EventType": "CONFIRM_SHIPMENT",
    "ShipmentNo": "1001816",
    "Status": "1444",
    "OrderDates": {
        "OrderDate": [{
                "ActualDate": "2019-08-01",
                "DateTypeId": "PROMISE_DATE",
                "OrderHeaderKey": "416734325",
                "OrderLineKey": "123416734326",
                "OrderReleaseKey": "",
                "Extn": {
                    "Ext": [{
                            "a": 1,
                            "b": 2,
                            "c": 3
                        }, {
                            "a": 8,
                            "b": 9
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }, {
                "ActualDate": "2020-03-22",
                "CommittedDate": "2020-03-22",
                "DateTypeId": "SHIPPED_OR_CANCELLED",
                "OrderHeaderKey": "416734325",
                "OrderLineKey": "123416734326",
                "OrderReleaseKey": " ",
                "RequestedDate": "2020-03-22"
            }
        ]
    },
    "ShipDates": {
        "ShipDate": [{
                "ActualDate": "2019-08-01",
                "DateTypeId": "PROMISE_DATE",
                "OrderHeaderKey": "416734325",
                "OrderLineKey": "123416734326",
                "Entn": {
                    "Ext": [{
                            "p": 1,
                            "q": 2,
                        }, {
                            "p": 9,
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }, {
                "ActualDate": "2020-03-22",
                "CommittedDate": "2020-03-22",
                "DateTypeId": "SHIPPED_OR_CANCELLED",
                "OrderHeaderKey": "416734325",
                "OrderLineKey": "123416734326",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The tree structure of the above sample json file is in this image:
[image: this image].

How can I get separate structures in python like in this image:
[image: this image]

I'm trying to do this either in an AWS Lambda function or a Glue job.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: have you tried relationalize and then loop through dfc.keys to write each frame as a new table ?

Comment: Hi Prabhakar, Yes we have tried relationalize transform. The problem with that approach is that the relational tables it creates can be different for different instances of the same event file, since the json event files don't have a standard structure. Is there a way to ensure dictionaries and lists in the json document are treated alike and get relationalized in sepearet table.

Comment: you can simply write each dynamic frame from the collection to separate path and have a crawler crawl this data. Crawler can maintain a common schema even though there are differences in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can try (but rename the final columns as you need):

```py
data = {
    "Shipment": {
        "ActualShipmentDate": "2020-03-22",
        "EnterpriseCode": "US001",
        "EventType": "CONFIRM_SHIPMENT",
        "ShipmentNo": "1001816",
        "Status": "1444",
        "OrderDates": {
            "OrderDate": [
                {
                    "ActualDate": "2019-08-01",
                    "DateTypeId": "PROMISE_DATE",
                    "OrderHeaderKey": "416734325",
                    "OrderLineKey": "123416734326",
                    "OrderReleaseKey": "",
                    "Extn": {
                        "Ext": [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, {"a": 8, "b": 9}]
                    },
                },
                {
                    "ActualDate": "2020-03-22",
                    "CommittedDate": "2020-03-22",
                    "DateTypeId": "SHIPPED_OR_CANCELLED",
                    "OrderHeaderKey": "416734325",
                    "OrderLineKey": "123416734326",
                    "OrderReleaseKey": " ",
                    "RequestedDate": "2020-03-22",
                },
            ]
        },
        "ShipDates": {
            "ShipDate": [
                {
                    "ActualDate": "2019-08-01",
                    "DateTypeId": "PROMISE_DATE",
                    "OrderHeaderKey": "416734325",
                    "OrderLineKey": "123416734326",
                    "Entn": {
                        "Ext": [
                            {
                                "p": 1,
                                "q": 2,
                            },
                            {
                                "p": 9,
                            },
                        ]
                    },
                },
                {
                    "ActualDate": "2020-03-22",
                    "CommittedDate": "2020-03-22",
                    "DateTypeId": "SHIPPED_OR_CANCELLED",
                    "OrderHeaderKey": "416734325",
                    "OrderLineKey": "123416734326",
                },
            ]
        },
    }
}

df1 = pd.json_normalize(data["Shipment"]["OrderDates"]["OrderDate"])
df2 = pd.json_normalize(data["Shipment"]["ShipDates"]["ShipDate"])

for i, col in enumerate(
    [
        "ActualShipmentDate",
        "EnterpriseCode",
        "EventType",
        "ShipmentNo",
        "Status",
    ]
):
    df1.insert(i, col, data["Shipment"][col])
    df2.insert(i, col, data["Shipment"][col])


df1 = df1.explode("Extn.Ext").reset_index(drop=True)
tmp = df1.pop("Extn.Ext")
df1 = pd.concat(
    [df1, tmp[tmp.notna()].reset_index(drop=True).apply(pd.Series)], axis=1
)

df2 = df2.explode("Entn.Ext").reset_index(drop=True)
tmp = df2.pop("Entn.Ext")
df2 = pd.concat(
    [df2, tmp[tmp.notna()].reset_index(drop=True).apply(pd.Series)], axis=1
)

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
  ActualShipmentDate EnterpriseCode         EventType ShipmentNo Status  ActualDate            DateTypeId OrderHeaderKey  OrderLineKey OrderReleaseKey CommittedDate RequestedDate    a    b    c
0         2020-03-22          US001  CONFIRM_SHIPMENT    1001816   1444  2019-08-01          PROMISE_DATE      416734325  123416734326                           NaN           NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0
1         2020-03-22          US001  CONFIRM_SHIPMENT    1001816   1444  2019-08-01          PROMISE_DATE      416734325  123416734326                           NaN           NaN  8.0  9.0  NaN
2         2020-03-22          US001  CONFIRM_SHIPMENT    1001816   1444  2020-03-22  SHIPPED_OR_CANCELLED      416734325  123416734326                    2020-03-22    2020-03-22  NaN  NaN  NaN

  ActualShipmentDate EnterpriseCode         EventType ShipmentNo Status  ActualDate            DateTypeId OrderHeaderKey  OrderLineKey CommittedDate    p    q
0         2020-03-22          US001  CONFIRM_SHIPMENT    1001816   1444  2019-08-01          PROMISE_DATE      416734325  123416734326           NaN  1.0  2.0
1         2020-03-22          US001  CONFIRM_SHIPMENT    1001816   1444  2019-08-01          PROMISE_DATE      416734325  123416734326           NaN  9.0  NaN
2         2020-03-22          US001  CONFIRM_SHIPMENT    1001816   1444  2020-03-22  SHIPPED_OR_CANCELLED      416734325  123416734326    2020-03-22  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej. This will mean hardcoding, however. I have more than 35 such different JSON files with different data and levels in each one of them. Is there any way to make this dynamic so that it logically identifies the different branches and normalizes each branch separately?